# Error with my .C files in my package?

Tags: r

I built my own package in R and it works very well. When I hit `build and load` in Rstudio, there are no errors at all. Everything is fine. However, When I run my function that include `.c` file I got this error:

```
Error in .C("SimulateRVine", as.integer(N), as.integer(n), as.integer(w1),  :  "SimulateRVine" not available for .C() for package "Vicop"!!
```

What is the problem and how can I solve it?

This is my own package so I rebuild it many times but nothing happen. When I try to use `useDynLib("Vicop")` and then rebuild my package I got an error. I think this is my problem but do not know how to solve it.

Comment: Can you copy in a reduced version of your C source and your DESCRIPTION file? Also, is it an option to switch to the newer .Call / Rcpp methods? Good tutorial at http://adv-r.had.co.nz/Rcpp.html

Comment: I need it to be in C files. Sorry, I do not understand your comment, would you like me to add my C source and DESCRIPTION file?

Comment: Is your package in a repository like github?  It would be useful to view more of the code to help you.

Comment: The question of using the C language is different from the "`.C` versus `.Call`" debate; in many places, `.Call` is strongly encouraged over `.C`. You can call C-based functions just fine with `.Call`.

Comment: @Alice yes please, seeing the source + DESCRIPTION would help us answer the question

Comment: @r2evans thanks for clarifying :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a hard search as a beginner to c language I see the problem.

I face this issue because I did not register my function. That is for each .c function I must register it in a file which is called int.c

That solve my problem.